# Blurry images in document

Tags: graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to obtain clear printed graphics with PCTeX v6](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17899/how-to-obtain-clear-printed-graphics-with-pctex-v6)

I am a beginner with LaTeX. I created this first document this evening.
My problem: I have inserted images in the document and I get them blurry in the preview not like in the original image.

[image]

How can I do to get them more high resolution .

Is there any way to change the resolution of images.

I'm using PCTeXv6.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: The resolution of included images is not changed by (La)TeX. The images look most likely blurry in the PDF because of scaling and anti-aliasing. See the answers to the question [Included PNG appears blurry in PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/included-png-appears-blurry-in-pdf) for an explanation.