# How to obtain clear printed graphics with PCTeX v6

Tags: graphics

I'm a beginner in LaTeX and I use PCTeX v6. Graphics inserted in my document are too fuzzy when I convert *.tex to *.avi or *. pdf formats.

They are produced by "Pacestar UML Diagrammer v6" and exported with resolution equal to 300dpi, but something about the graphics is "ugly".

Hopefully the following images can show this issue:

**[The original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNZ5x.png).**
[image: Original Image]
**[How the image appears in the document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q1tK.png).**
[image: Image as included in document]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.StackExchange. Would it be possible to provide a [MWE](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) and image to show what's causing your problem and what it looks like? As an aside, StackExchange sites don't require users to include a greeting in their posts.

Comment: It might be the fault of the PDF viewer. See [Included PNG appears blurry in PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/included-png-appears-blurry-in-pdf) for details.

Comment: Also have a look on [Quickest way to include graphics](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10966/quickest-way-to-include-graphics/10970#10970).

Answer (score 4):

A picture of the output would help in diagnosing the problem.

If the graphics are fuzzy, it is likely because they are being inserted as raster graphics (*e.g.*, if the graphics are being inserted as PNG or JPG images).  Even if the graphics are EPS or PDF they still may be raster, however that is a function of the program that created them in the first place.  I would suggest trying to export the graphics from UML Diagrammer in the form of an EPS file (if you are using `latex`) or a PDF (if you are using `pdflatex`). If that still produces fuzzy output, then this may be a limitation of UML Diagrammer.

For more information, I suggest you read the answers to [How do I insert an image in LaTeX so it looks good on print?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165/how-do-i-insert-an-image-in-latex-so-it-looks-good-on-print).

Comment: Below a picture 's preview when it's converted to *.dvi format [1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1q1tK.png

Comment: Does the document look just as bad when it is printed?  If not, then the problem is likely in your DVI renderer (*i.e.*, the file is actually fine, it's just being rendered to your computer screen poorly), and it will likely look better when you convert it to a PDF.  If so, then the problem is likely with your original image and/or the way in which you are importing it into LaTeX.

Comment: The original picture looks like >> http://i.stack.imgur.com/MNZ5x.png