# How to correctly include pixel graphics with pdflatex with consistent scaling across PDF viewers?

Tags: graphics, pdf, viewers

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Included PNG appears blurry in PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/included-png-appears-blurry-in-pdf)
>   [My pixel perfect picture gets blurry when compiled in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10975/my-pixel-perfect-picture-gets-blurry-when-compiled-in-latex)

I often need to use pixel graphics in LaTeX files (mostly screenshots), but I don’t really know what’s the best way to do it. Let me illustrate the problem I am having with the following minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{scrot.png}
\end{document}
```

You can get scrot.png from http://t.zekjur.net/tex/scrot.png (it’s just a screenshot I made with the tool `scrot`. Any pixel graphic will do).

After using `pdflatex mwe.tex` I get `mwe.pdf`. The picture in it looks good (sharp, not scaled but at its native size) in Xpdf when I chose 100% zoom level. **However**, when I open the same file with evince instead of Xpdf, I cannot get the picture to look good -- no matter which zoom level I choose.

This is what it looks like in Xpdf:

[image]

and this is what it looks like in evince:

[image]

What is the reason for this problem and what is a better way (aside from using vector graphics, obviously)?

Comment: This is probably Evince trying to be "clever", interpolating you image with the rather bad nearest-neighbour algorithm. There's not much you can do about it, AFAIK. At least that's what [this evince bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25268) suggests.

Comment: @You: Since when is nearest-neighbor considered in any sense "clever"? (Is it not the most naive rescaling algorithm known to man?)

Comment: @SamB: Sometimes _clever_ can mean not only _good_, but also _fast_. :-)

Comment: @You: OK, let’s assume Evince scales badly. Why is 100% in Evince a different size than 100% in Xpdf?

Comment: @Michael: Ask the developers. All I can say is that rendering is going to differ between viewers.

Comment: I closed this a duplicate to the above mentioned questions. If you think otherwise feel free to request the question being reopened.

Comment: @Michael: 100% differs because different applications have a different idea of what 100% means. Some applications assume that the screen resolution is, e.g., 96dpi, and then you might be lucky and get nice results if you include a 96dpi image and use 100% zoom. Some other applications use the physical resolution of your monitor (which might make sense with a monitor but is meaningless with a projector).