# Images (png) are very blurred when printing pdf (generated with pdflatex) from linux

Tags: graphics, pdftex, png

When I create a pdf file using pdflatex which includes png images the output of the pdf looks fine in my linux and windows pdf viewer.

However, when printing this file from linux to a network printer all png images look terrible blurry. The funny thing about this is that when I print it from windows to the same network printer the very same pdf file looks good.

I'm confused as I don't understand how this happens.

Does anyone had this issue before and knows how I can fix this?

Comment: I suspect this is off-topic, as the issue is not the PDF itself (as the Windows printing shows), but rather the print driver on Linux.

Comment: This can certainly be true but I have the feeling that there might be an actual problem with my pdf. E.g. when I print other pdfs (which contain images) I've never experienced this problem. Only with my own pdf created by pdflatex. Accordingly I worry that it has in fact something to do with wrong options in my latex file.

Comment: pdfTeX just includes the `.png` file you give it: see  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/included-png-appears-blurry-in-pdf for example. So if the `.png` is okay then it will work.

Comment: I've seen an issue that sounds similar on linux, which when you create a PDF with pdfLaTeX and open it in Kile or xpdf the images look blurry, but not when opened in Adobe. What program are you using to print it? I think it may be with the PDF viewer.

Comment: @Canageek, thank you for your suggestions, I probably should try to print it with adobe from linux. I've used evince. The only funny thing is that on the screen it looks all really good and nice. Will post the results with adobe in a minute.

Comment: so, the problem is (kind of) solved. Printing from linux using adobe instead of evince gives the right result. I will now try xpdf and other pdf viewer just to see if it is only a problem with evince. But thanks to all for suggestions... Finally I will be able to print my thesis on time.

Comment: surprisingly in xpdf all the images in question are not there at all. Did anyone have that issue before?

Comment: I've not heard of that one. Odd, I thought evince was just a frontend to xpdf.

Comment: Can you post a MWE with the png you are using? Also, what version of pdflatex?

Comment: I think the subject can be closed. It is difficult to find out now what the origin of this mysterious behaviour is. Probably it is far too specific and may just have to do with the exact version of evince / poppler etc I'm using.