# Error with using \pdfpxdimen: "Undefined control sequence"

Tags: xetex, errors, pdf

I am trying to change the DPI of the output PDF using `\pdfpxdimen` in the preamble, but it returns an error:

```
"! Undefined control sequence \pdfpxdimen".
```

I guess that is because I am using XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX. If it is so, is there any way to change the DPI using XeLaTeX?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\pdfpxdimen=1in % 1 DPI
\divide\pdfpxdimen by 96 % 96 DPI

\begin{document}
some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't work: XeTeX doesn't know that primitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't "change the dpi". You are only changing the value of the "px" unit. Try this with pdflatex to understand what's happening:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\begin{document}

\pdfpxdimen=1in % 
a\hspace{1px}b 

\pdfpxdimen=2in % 
a\hspace{1px}b
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, I see. But this px value changing has a side effect, that I need: increasing sharpness of included images (for example according to this — http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/included-png-appears-blurry-in-pdf). Can I do same thing with xelatex?

Comment: Changing the size of an image can naturally increase the sharpness. But I doubt very much that you can get some additional improvements by using `\pdfxdimen`: imho it only helps with the calculation of a good size.