# How to avoid bad quality image

Tags: beamer, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Included PNG appears blurry in PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/included-png-appears-blurry-in-pdf)

I have a PNG image with a pretty good quality, but when I import this in `beamer` it has lost its quality, even if I maintain the 1.0 as scale factor. How can I avoid it? Is vectorial image the one solution? I grab this image from a website. I use this code to import image:

```
\begin{figure}[here]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{img/dp2}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I'm using `pdflatex`.

PS: I have no type of knowledge about graphic and photoediting.
[image: Original image, on the left looks bigger when imported ad 1 as scale factor]

Comment: The image quality should not be changed. Could it be that you have a different version of the same file in the same directory, like `img/dp2.jpg`? `\includegraphics` tries a list of file extensions and by default JPG comes before PNG. Try it with the `.png` added. Also, how are you compiling the document? Using `pdflatex` or `latex` etc.?

Comment: BTW, the `[here]` is wrong, it should be `[h]`. See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017) for more details about figure placement. Also see [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651) to learn why you should use `\centering` instead of `{center}`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: pdflatex

Comment: With `pdflatex` there should be no problem. Please check the `.log` file if really the wanted image is used and not a different one. As I said, also try `{img/dp2.png}`.

Comment: No way. Image is 510x347 and when imported at full scale (1 factor) looks bigger than original (see image added to original question).

Comment: How do you know that it has lost quality?  What tests are you using?  What happens if you include it in a normal LaTeX document (ie with the article class instead of beamer)?

Comment: Scale your image to three quarters of its original size, thus use `scale=0.75`. In the document it then should appear properly.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig it's properly fit horizzontally but not vertically. And result is always the same, completely bad.

Comment: Ok, here we go: This is most likely be caused by a wrong image resolution. LaTeX seems to use a wrong number of DPIs. See [Included png appears too big in PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1155/2975), which might help. Also opening and resaving the image might fix the DPI metadata.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [Included PNG appears blurry in PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1162/2975). Please have a look at the answers there.